# URL to static files with django-storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

I have set Django to serve static files from an S3 bucket using django-storages.

Unfortunately the urls to the static files look like:

```
https://[bucket name].s3.amazonaws.com/profile_pics/[filename]?AWSAccessKeyId=[...]&Signature=[...]&Expires=[...]
```

Is there way to encode the urls to avoid revealing the AWS access key and signature?

Answer (score 5):

Eventually I found out that to hide the Access Key and Signature from the url it is sufficient to add

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

in settings.py and set the S3 bucket as public.

Answer (score 0):

That's how S3 works when you're trying to share your private resources on S3 for your customers. With the access key id and the signature, your customer can use it to access to your resource for short amount of time and then it will be expired.

Take a look at [Signed URL document](http://Here's%20an%20overview%20of%20how%20you%20configure%20CloudFront%20and%20Amazon%20S3%20for%20signed%20URLs%20and%20how%20CloudFront%20responds%20when%20a%20user%20uses%20a%20signed%20URL%20to%20request%20a%20file.%20%20In%20your%20CloudFront%20distribution,%20specify%20one%20or%20more%20trusted%20signers,%20which%20are%20the%20AWS%20accounts%20that%20you%20want%20to%20have%20permission%20to%20create%20signed%20URLs.%20%20For%20more%20information,%20see%20Specifying%20the%20AWS%20Accounts%20That%20Can%20Create%20Signed%20URLs%20and%20Signed%20Cookies%20(Trusted%20Signers).%20%20You%20develop%20your%20application%20to%20determine%20whether%20a%20user%20should%20have%20access%20to%20your%20content%20and%20to%20create%20signed%20URLs%20for%20the%20files%20or%20parts%20of%20your%20application%20that%20you%20want%20to%20restrict%20access%20to.%20For%20more%20information,%20see%20the%20following%20topics:%20%20Creating%20a%20Signed%20URL%20Using%20a%20Canned%20Policy%20%20Creating%20a%20Signed%20URL%20Using%20a%20Custom%20Policy%20%20A%20user%20requests%20a%20file%20for%20which%20you%20want%20to%20require%20signed%20URLs.%20%20Your%20application%20verifies%20that%20the%20user%20is%20entitled%20to%20access%20the%20file:%20they've%20signed%20in,%20they've%20paid%20for%20access%20to%20the%20content,%20or%20they've%20met%20some%20other%20requirement%20for%20access.%20%20Your%20application%20creates%20and%20returns%20a%20signed%20URL%20to%20the%20user.%20%20The%20signed%20URL%20allows%20the%20user%20to%20download%20or%20stream%20the%20content.%20%20This%20step%20is%20automatic;%20the%20user%20usually%20doesn't%20have%20to%20do%20anything%20additional%20to%20access%20the%20content.%20For%20example,%20if%20a%20user%20is%20accessing%20your%20content%20in%20a%20web%20browser,%20your%20application%20returns%20the%20signed%20URL%20to%20the%20browser.%20The%20browser%20immediately%20uses%20the%20signed%20URL%20to%20access%20the%20file%20in%20the%20CloudFront%20edge%20cache%20without%20any%20intervention%20from%20the%20user.%20%20CloudFront%20uses%20the%20public%20key%20to%20validate%20the%20signature%20and%20confirm%20that%20the%20URL%20hasn't%20been%20tampered%20with.%20If%20the%20signature%20is%20invalid,%20the%20request%20is%20rejected.%20%20If%20the%20signature%20is%20valid,%20CloudFront%20looks%20at%20the%20policy%20statement%20in%20the%20URL%20(or%20constructs%20one%20if%20you're%20using%20a%20canned%20policy)%20to%20confirm%20that%20the%20request%20is%20still%20valid.%20For%20example,%20if%20you%20specified%20a%20beginning%20and%20ending%20date%20and%20time%20for%20the%20URL,%20CloudFront%20confirms%20that%20the%20user%20is%20trying%20to%20access%20your%20content%20during%20the%20time%20period%20that%20you%20want%20to%20allow%20access.%20%20If%20the%20request%20meets%20the%20requirements%20in%20the%20policy%20statement,%20CloudFront%20does%20the%20standard%20operations:%20determines%20whether%20the%20file%20is%20already%20in%20the%20edge%20cache,%20forwards%20the%20request%20to%20the%20origin%20if%20necessary,%20and%20returns%20the%20file%20to%20the%20user.%20%20Note%20Signed%20CloudFront%20URLs%20cannot%20contain%20extra%20query%20string%20arguments.%20If%20you%20add%20a%20query%20string%20to%20a%20signed%20URL%20after%20you%20create%20it,%20the%20URL%20returns%20an%20HTTP%20403%20status.) here to see how it works.

Hope that helps!